# SFSafariViewController not dismissing properly (iOS 10.3)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sfsafariviewcontroller

In my app I have a `SFSafariViewController` that I am displaying modally. Upon dismissal, the presenting ViewController does not have its `dismiss` method called. Code for my subclass of `UIViewController`:

```
override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    print("will present")
    super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag) {
        completion?()
        print("did present")
    }
}

override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    print("will dismiss)")
    super.dismiss(animated: flag) {
        completion?()
        print("did dismiss")
    }
}

func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
    print("finished with \(controller)")
}


func testSVC() {
    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!)
    svc.delegate = self

    self.present(svc, animated: true) {
        print("presented \(svc)")
    }
}
```

Calling `testSVC()` and then tapping "Done" in the SafariViewController produces the following output:

```
will present
presented <SFSafariViewController: 0x7fd981b2f200>
did present
finished with <SFSafariViewController: 0x7fd981b2f200>
```

And that's it. The `dismiss` print statements are missing. Can anyone help me figure out why `dismiss` is not being called? I thought that all `UIViewController` dismissals were forwarded to the presenting `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

When you dismiss the SFSafariViewController the dismiss method for svc is fired not the ViewController you're in. If you want to override the dismiss for the SFSafariViewController then you should subclass it and override the dismiss func in that subclass.

Comment: But doesn't that `dismiss` method get forwarded to the presenting `UIViewController`? Which in this case is the one whose code I'm showing.

Comment: The documentation does say that it should get passed down to the presenting view controller but I just tested it and it doesn't. I subclassed the SFSafariViewController and override the dismiss func and it was being hit when done was being pressed. Your best bet would be to subclass it.

Comment: Must be a bug. Because at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss it clearly states "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal."